# estimate the maximum error of taylor approximation of $\ln(x)$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

find the error bound using the Lagrange Remainder:
$$\ln(x)\approx (x-1)-\frac{(x-1)^2}{2}+\frac{(x-1)^3}{3}, |x-1|<\dfrac{1}{64}$$

My attempt:
\begin{align}
R_3(x)&=\dfrac{f^{(4)}(c)}{4!}(x-1)^4\\
f^{4}(c)&=\dfrac{-6}{(x-1)^4}\\
\implies R_3(x)&=\dfrac{-6}{4!}\dfrac{(x-1)^4}{(c-1)^4}\\
\implies |R_3(x)|&\leq \dfrac{6}{4!}\dfrac{(\frac{1}{64})^4}{(\frac{-1}{64})^4}=.25
\end{align}
Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that,

\begin{equation}
f(x) = log(x) \implies f^{(4)}(x) = \frac{-6}{x^4}
\end{equation}

Therefore,
\begin{equation}
R_3(x) = -\frac{6}{4!c^4}(x-1)^4\quad; \quad \text{where } c \text{ is in between 1 and x}
\end{equation}

Since $c$ depends on $x$, first find an upper bound as;

\begin{equation}
|R_3(x)| \leq
\begin{cases}
\frac{6}{4!}(x-1)^4 \quad &if \quad x>1\\
\frac{6}{4!x^4}(x-1)^4 \quad &if \quad x<1
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

Now we can bound for $|x-1|<1/64$,

\begin{equation}
|R_3(x)| \leq
\begin{cases}
\frac{6}{4!64^4} \quad &if \quad x>1\\
\frac{6}{4!(1-1/64)^464^4} \quad &if \quad x<1
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

Here is a plot done by [wolframalpha.com](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20%7Clog(x)%20-%20(x-1)%20%2B%20(x-1)%5E2%2F2%20-%20(x-1)%5E3%2F3%7C%20and%206%2F4!%2F64%5E4%20and%206%2F4!%2F63%5E4%20from%201-1%2F64%20to%201%2B1%2F64).
You can visaully see that we need two different bounds for $x<1$ and $x>1$. If you need a single bound, $x<1$ case will work.

Comment: If x was 0.3 in the above, isn't the Remainder bound then very large and gets worse as you add more terms?

Comment: @Cliff Stamp, I couldn't understand your question, can you explain what you mean by adding more terms? (There is a condition for last bound, $|x-1|<1/64$.)

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear, say the bound on x was between 0.3 and 1.

Comment: Then since $x<1$, $|R_3(x)| \leq \frac{6(0.7)^4}{4!(0.3)^4}$.

Comment: Thanks, that was what I thought. This was an old question on an AP Math exam, but it matches none of the given answers.